# CocoaPods - How to change the user information that gets generated when creating a new podspec?

Tags: git, caching, cocoapods, account, podspec

I am creating some new CocoaPods, but it looks like my old GitHub account information is still cached and gets generated in the podspec. How do I update this?

I verified my GitHub account has the correct information, and that only my current account appears in macOS KeyChain, but I still keep getting old company name and email generated when running `pod lib create MyProject`.

I am talking about these items in **MyProject.podspec**:

```
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/OLD_COMPANY_NAME/MyProject'
  s.author           = { 'OLD_COMPANY_NAME' => 'me@OLD_COMPANY_NAME.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/OLD_COMPANY_NAME/MyProject.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

Comment: If you do `$>git config --list`, you don't see your old company id ?

Comment: @Larme Nope, I only see the new info.